# Apart from a timeout, is it possible for a request to be received by the server but still a VolleyError be found on the client side?

Tags: android-volley

Apart from a timeout, is it possible for a request to be received by the server but still a `VolleyError` be found on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Error code 307 for instance occurs when a resource is temporarily not available but available on a different url which the server returns. So in this case, the client side gets an error.